# Disable selection of controls by arrow keys in a form

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I disable selection of controls when pressing arrow keys on a Windows Form? 
For example when I press up and down while a combobox is focused, it selects some elements, or if there is a toolbar focused, it selects different buttons.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could intercept the arrow keypresses and simply not react:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (!msg.HWnd.Equals(this.Handle) && 
        (keyData == Keys.Left || keyData == Keys.Right ||
        keyData == Keys.Up || keyData == Keys.Down))
        return true;
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

You may want to put focus somewhere harmless first, otherwise, you could force this to "lock on" to a control where you do not want activity.

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed.  Lower-level approach, then.

Comment: My form intercepts Arrow Keys, but I use their events for another function. The problem is that when I realize the other things, if there is a focused control, it does the behaviour described above, plus my function! I just want it to realize my function and nothing else.

Comment: So you _only_ want to disable the arrow key reactions for _specific controls_?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Not exactly. I want to disable the Arrow key reactions for _every_ control except from .this (or Form).

Comment: See edit...added check for form handle.  Meaning that if the call is **not** coming from the form, **and** it's an arrow key... _do nothing_.

Comment: Thanks! Where should I put this code? As en event of form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49837/discussion-between-misime-and-donboitnott)